# Convert triple integral in cylindrical coordinates to spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

I have this math problem right now, and any way I look at it, it just seems impossible. I don't understand.

So I am given the integral:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} r^2\,
dz\,dr\,d\theta
$$

The exercise is to convert (no need to calculate) the integral to cartesian and spherical coordinates.
I managed the conversion to cartesian coordinates and I got:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,
dz\,dy\,dx
$$

But the conversion to spherical coordinates seems just impossible. I don't understand at all.

I am given a "hint" that I need to give the integral in multiple parts. What really throws me off though, is that the area that I'm integrating is clearly a cylinder, only the top is spherical.

I would appreciate help in figuring out how this is possible.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: instead of going to Cartesian, can you find a set of three equations that gives you cylindrical coordinates in terms of spherical coordinates directly? (Extra hint: this reduces your burden to a $2$D problem in which you can draw the regions and algebraically find the bounds more easily)

Comment: Firstly you can reduce area to first quadrant in cartesian coordinates and then wright direct equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I show here a drawing of your domain, projected in the $x-z$ plane, with $x$ horizontal and $y$ vertical.[image: view]
Then the radius of integration in spherical coordinates is between the origin an d the black dot. The angle with respect to $z$ axis is $t$ in the figure. As mentioned in the question, you have two domains. While the projection in the horizontal plane is less than $1$, your upper limit is $2$. If the projection is greater than $1$, you only integrate to $1/\sin t$. Why that value? Because than the projection in the plane is $$\frac 1{\sin t}\sin t=1$$
Alternatively, just from a notation point of view, you can put the upper limit  for $r$ to be $$\min\left(2,\frac 1{\sin t}\right)$$
In practice, you have domains where the polar angle is below and above $\arcsin\frac12=\frac\pi6$

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. I feel stupid for not realizing it right away.